# Select N unique rows randomly while excluding 1 specific row (in SQLite DB)

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, random

I need to select `x` unique rows randomly from a table with `n` rows, while excluding 1 specific row. (`x` is small, 3 for example) This can be done in several queries if needed and I can also compute anything in programming language (Java). The one important thing is that it must be done faster than `O(n)`, consuming `O(x)` memory and indefinite looping (retrying) is also undesirable.

Probability of selection should be equal for all rows (except the one which is excluded, of course)

#### Example:

```
| id | some data |
|————|———————————|
|  1 |     …     |
|  2 |     …     |
|  3 |     …     |
|  4 |     …     |
|  5 |     …     |
```

The algorithm is ran with arguments (x = 3, exclude_id = 4), so:
it should select 3 different random rows from rows with id in `1,2,3,5`.

#### (end of example)

I tried the following approach:

- get row count (= n);
- get the position of the excluded row by something like `select count(*) where id < excluded_id`, assuming id is monotonically increasing;
- select the numbers from `0..n`, obeying all the rules, by using some "clever" algorithms, it's something like `O(x)`, in other words fast enough;
- select these x rows one by one by using `limit(index, 1)` SQL clause.

**However,** it turned out that it's possible for rows to change positions (I'm not sure why), so the auto-generated ids are not monotonically increasing. And in this case the second step (get the position of the excluded row) produces wrong result and the algorithm fails to do its job correctly.

How can this be improved?

Also, if this is vastly easier with a different SQL-like database system, it would be interesting, too. (the DB is on a server and I can install any software there as long as it's compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help communicate what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added the example, thank you for suggestion

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it would be needed to do in every query, right? but that's interesting idea, I'll try it

Comment: Are the IDs guaranteed to be consecutive?

Comment: @CL. No, there can be "holes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm sorry for a bit of confusion;) the algorithm I used is actually correct it the `id` is monotonically increasing, I just forgot that it was not itself auto-generated, it was taken from another table where it's auto-generated, and it was possible to add these rows in different order.

So I added another id for this table, which is auto-generated, and used it for row selection, and now it works as it should.